# How can i improve this with linq?

Tags: c#, linq

I have this piece of code:

```
foreach(var planning in Planning)
{

    if (onlyOneMatrice)
    {
        if (idMatrice == null || planning.IDMatrice == idMatrice)
        {
            idMatrice = planning.IDMatrice;
        }
        else
        {
            onlyOneMatrice = false;
        }
    }
    else
            {
                idMatrice = null;
                _ErrorMatrice = $"Error";
            }
    }
}
```

who's ugly. I'm trying to use Linq to reduce it, but I must be mistaken somewhere. There is my test :

```
bool IsMonoOrEmptyMatrice()
{
    var id = Planning.FirstOrDefault(x=> { return x.IDMatrice != null});
    return id==null || Planning.All( x => { return x.IDMatrice == null || x.IDMatrice == id});
}
```

But it return null everytime.

I have an observableCollection"Planning", each object containing an "idMatrice" data.
What I'm trying to check is that all the idMatrices on a list are identical.

Example: for an object "A" that you are scanning, all the matrices must be identical. If two different matrices are found, I would return an error message.

I also thought of something like :

```
Planning.Distinct().Count() > 1 ? "somethingHere" : null ;
```

If anyone has a suggestion..... Thank you in advance

Edit : Planning object :

```
    public partial class Planning
{
    public System.DateTime Jour { get; set; }
    public string Matricule { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Cycle { get; set; }
    public string Type_Jour { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> Heure_début1 { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> Heure_fin1 { get; set; }
    public string Type_Prise1 { get; set; }
    public string IDEtablissement1 { get; set; }
    public string IDSection1 { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Couleur1 { get; set; }
    public bool Visible1 { get; set; }
    public string Type_Durée { get; set; }
    public string IDEtablissement_Durée { get; set; }
    public string IDSection_Durée { get; set; }
    public string IDService_Durée { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> Date_MAJ { get; set; }
    public string IDMatrice { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Can you add `Planning` class code? (not the collection, but the single object type)

Comment: Wait... `if(planning.IDMatrice == idMatrice){idMatrice = planning.IDMatrice;}`?

Comment: sure it's done, thanks

Comment: Why aren't you using `.GroupBy()`? that way you can divide the list up in groups based on matriceID, and if there is more than 1 group, throw error.

Comment: @Sephystos What's the behaviour you want to have if `IDMatrice` is null? always return error or if all objects have `IDMatrice` null, consider it identical?

Comment: Matrix Id is never supposed to be null, but if it is, I would like to return an error message too, good point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check if this snippet of code suits your request

```cs
// check if any IdMatrice is null
if(Planning.Any(p => p.IDMatrice == null))
    //return error

if(Planning.GroupBy(p => p.IDMatrice).Count() > 1)
    // list is not identical
else
    // list is identical
```

Comment: It seems to be working perfectly. Can you just explain to me the usefulness of "GroupBy" in this context?

Comment: @Sephystos `GroupBy` function here creates an `IEnumerable` that contains a list of `IGrouping` (basically another list) where `Planning` objects with the same `IDMatrice` are grouped; So if there's more than one list in what GroupBy returns, that means that `Planning` object are grouped in more than one list, that's because not all IDMatrice are the same.

Comment: Oh, i see. Thanks for the help